# Override back button in app android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Made an application in android, back buttons also are handled, like a web site?

If so, these buttons are programmed as any button or whether they are default for all applications?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android requires the existence of a Back button (along with power and volume control). Either a hardware button or a software, always visible navigation bar.

In general the default handling of the button will work in most instances. It will go back through an app's previous activities and close the app once it reaches the end of the stack. The same can be configured to work with fragment stacks too.

You can opt to override the default implementation though if you choose to. In any activity you want to manually control the action when a user presses back:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // custom actions
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes exactly ! You have just to override the public void onBackPressed().

You can handle it using: for API level 5

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
}
```

For versions older then API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: The fact you included pre API 5 makes me happy. Poor pre API 9 always gets left out.

Answer (score 0):

To start an action on back pressed, go to an activity on Android, add this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //action here!
}
```

or, you can program your own button, using normal buttons...